# Python: iterate over boolean array

Tags: python

How can I iterate over a boolean array?
My current apprroach is not working for booleans...

```
a = [[True, False, True], [True, False, False]]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        print(a[i][j], end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: That runs fine for me. You'll have to tell us what "not working" means.

Comment: `for l in a: for b in l: print(b, end=" ")`. No need for `range` and `len` at all…

Comment: `for l in a: print(*l)` does the same thing…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me, but maybe you want something like this, which is a bit easier than doing it with ranges:

```
a = [[True, False, True], [True, False, False]]
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        print(j, end=" ")
    print()
```